# Is there an extension to beautify a Processing sketch?

Tags: formatting, processing

I haven't used Processing in many years. I am copying some old code into Processing and it is pasting onto one line. Is there a beautify extension for Processing 3? Have looked and can't find.

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're talking about is called **auto-formatting**, not beautifying.

The Processing editor includes an auto-formatter. Just go to Edit > Auto-Format, or press ctrl+t to do it from the keyboard.

Alternatively, most code IDEs like eclipse also include auto-formatters.

However, if everything is on one line, it sounds like you're dealing with an issue copying the newline character. This can happen if you copy something from one OS to another, for example. You might be able to google for a tool that fixes this problem, but it might be simpler to just put in the line breaks manually and then use the auto-formatter to handle the indentation for you.